# Remove row class from table -Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table .Table id is resultTable.  Some of the rows in the table have a class.

How can i remove those classes from that table.

I am using the code given below to add the class

```
     $('#resultTable tr').click(function (event) {
       $(this).addClass("test");
       });
```

TO remove the class test from  the entire table , i tried the code given below

```
   $('#resultTable').removeClass("test");
```

But its not working.Any ideas?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You forgot a `tr`

```
$('#resultTable tr').removeClass("test");
```

Answer (score 6):

To remove all classes from all table rows of the `resultTable`:

```
$('#resultTable tr').removeAttr('class');
```

To remove just the `class` of 'test':

```
$('#resultTable tr.test').removeClass('test');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#resultTable').find('.test').each(function(){
  $(this).removeClass("test");
});
```